# Full Hexadecimal Representation in Python?

Tags: python, rsa, hex

I've writing a RSA implementation in Python and have now successfully encrypted it however when it prints out the cipher, every time it comes out '0x1L.' I believe this is a long number, however I do not know how to show the full number. If my code is required, I will post in the comments section( It is quite long).

Thanks

Comment: Better post the relevant section of your code (meaning that which we need to reproduce the problem - no more, no less) in your question. Comments don't handle more than one line of code well.

Comment: The `type` of the number is `long`, but it shouldn't be suppressing any output -- you're probably just always getting `1` as a result.

Comment: Obviously you have a bug in your program, your understanding of RSA, or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's representation of your result as `0x1L` indicates the number's type and value - however, it doesn't truncate the number at all. While it is stored as a `long` internally, its value is still just `1` in this case.